# JPA and QueryDSL: no delete found for type

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I just wanted to ask, what this generically means:

`Invalid derived query! No property delete found for type:`

it is occurring for a method in my class that implements the JPARepository class (spring framework). I just wanted to understand what the error meant/was trying to tell me.

Comment: What does your query look like? What version of Spring-Data-JPA are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [Spring Data: "delete by" is supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723025/spring-data-delete-by-is-supported/23731038#23731038) it is likely that you are using and older version of spring-jpa which does not support delete methods yet. You can either upgrade the dependency or use a query for your method:

```
@Modifying
@Query("Delete from #{#entityName} t where t.userId= ?1")
public void deleteByUserId(String userId);
```