# Spring Repository Delete With Specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Spring's `CrudRepository` provides some delete methods while `JpaSpecificationExecutor` does not. I'd like to delete based on a `Specification` -- just like I'm doing for querying. Is there a way to do this?

Justification: I want to be sure a user owns the resource during deletion instead of allowing direct access to the resource based on the id (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

Options I see:

- Use `@Query` on a custom delete method in the repository. Something like `delete from Entity e where e in (select e from Entity e where ...)`. This works fine, but I'd like to re-use other code and not have to manually create the query.
- Fetch the entities then delete them. This seems wasteful to fetch and then delete when it can be done in one go.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23723675/3166303

Comment: @leeor Yes, that's using a custom `@Query` which works, but I'd like to re-use a `Specification` which I use for all other query methods.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple you can use `List<YourReturnType> result = yourRepository.findAll(specification);` to query your records and then use `yourRepository.deleteAll(result);` to delete all those records.

Comment: You will fetch all the entities and then delete them. Is there a way to delete directly?