# what is the best way to save or update or delete collection of entities using spring data jpa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Employee. 
For example: 
I have saved few records into database like below:

```
employeeRepository.save(employees);
```

In next request, I would like to update few saved entities and delete few saved entities and create few entities newly.

Please let me know the easy way to do it in Spring data JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate and Use **EmployeeRepository**
To instantiate our **EmployeeRepository** that has extended **CrudRepository**, we can use dependency injection.

```
public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired    
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee){
    employeeRepository.save(employee);  
    }
    List<Employee> saveEmployee(List<Employee> employees){
        for(Employee employee:employees){
            saveEmployee(employee);         }   
    } 
    void deleteEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeRepository.delete(employee);
    }
    void deleteEmployee(List<Employee> employees){
        for(Employee employee:employees){
            deleteEmployee(employee);
        }
    } 
}
```

Now we are ready to use methods of CrudRepository. Find the example for some of its methods.

1. Create and Update one entity:

Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

2. Delete one entity::

employeeRepository.delete(employee);

If you perform bulk operation then you can override **saveEmployee()** and **deleteEmployee()** on **EmployeeService** class.

Answer (score 0):

You mainly want to derive on `Spring Data JPA`s derived query features as much as possible! You definitely don't want to write your own boilerplate code because that defeats the purpose of `Spring Data JPA` entirely!

**Delete**

The best (and cleanest) way to do this is to let `Spring Data JPA` *derive* the query for you:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

    Long deleteByIdIn(List<Long> employeeIdsToDelete);

}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723025/spring-data-delete-by-is-supported).

**Update**

Updates can be done this way:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Employee empl set empl.param =:param where empl.id =:emplId")
void updateEmployees(@Param("emplId") Long emplId, @Param("param") paramValue);
```

And otherwise can be done with a combination of find and modify (likely in the `Service` method:

```
public void myEmployeeServiceUpdateMethod(List<Long> emplIds) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findByIdIn(emplIds);
    employees.forEach(empl -> empl.setParam("NewParam!");
}
```

And Spring JPA will automatically flush and update those values for you!

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741102/how-to-beautifully-update-a-jpa-entity-in-spring-data/39746931).

**Create**

Creates you're already doing right. Just pass in the list of new entities to `#save`.