# Could not extract ResultSet when performing customized native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and I want to encapsulate a method which performs specific SQL. I do it in the following matter:

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
  @Query(
      value = "delete from User u where u.alias = :alias",
      nativeQuery = true
      )
  void deleteUserByAlias(@Param("alias") String alias);
}
```

However, I got the following message as the result:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-12-11T15:54:54.627+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet",
  "path": "/user/delete"
}
```

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 12):

If your method is already Transactional , then please use transactional on repository method also

```
@Component
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

      @Query(
          value = "delete from User u where u.alias = :alias",
          nativeQuery = true
          )
      @Modifying
      @Transactional
      void deleteUserByAlias(@Param("alias") String alias);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work on my side.

Comment: what is your table name in the database?

Comment: Thank you, `@Modifying`, `@Transactional` on method solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

```
@Repository
@Transactional
interface OrderRepository: JpaRepository<Order, OrderIdentity>{

   @Query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id=:id",nativeQuery = true)
   fun findBy(@Param("id") id: String): List<OrderEvent>

   @Modifying
   @Query("DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
   fun deleteFor(@Param("id") id: String)

}
```

By using @Modifying on method and @Transactional on Repository error will be resolved.

Comment: This is the correct answer: ```@Modifying``` on the method and ```@Transactional``` on the Repo. Do not put both on anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

your class should be like this:

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

  @Query(
      value = "delete from User u where u.alias = :alias",
      nativeQuery = true
      )
  @Modifying
  void deleteUserByAlias(@Param("alias") String alias);
}
```

As you can see I am using @Modifying, for more information take a look to this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the error is still there based on your advice.

Comment: you should combine '@Transactional' on the interface level and '@Modifying' on the method level then it should work

Answer (score 0):

Not answer my question directly, but found a workaround to remove record based on other attribute but not ID.
According to answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23731038/3378204),

> Derivation of delete queries using given method name is supported
>   starting with version 1.6.0.RC1 of Spring Data JPA. The keywords
>   remove and delete are supported. As return value one can choose
>   between the number or a list of removed entities.
>
> Long removeByLastname(String lastname);
>
> List deleteByLastname(String lastname);

I can write

```
  @Transactional
  void deleteByAlias(String alias);
```

at `UserRepository` to achieve the goal.

I won't accept this answer and open for any further contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the param you are passing is not null. it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This answer actually helped me. I wasn't using Spring, though. Calling `query.setParameter("column", variable)` with `variable` `null` can throw an error with the same message.